# problem with login page ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, controller

I'm following a tutorial: http://visionmasterdesigns.com/tutorial-create-a-login-system-in-ruby-on-rails/
to create a login page

when I try to do this part:

```
def authenticate
02.        #User.new(params[:userform]) will create a new object of User, retrieve values from the form and store it variable @user.
03.        @user = User.new(params[:userform])
04.        #find records with username,password
05.        valid_user = User.find(:first,:conditions => ["user_name = ? and password = ?",@user.user_name, @user.password])
06. 
07.        #if statement checks whether valid_user exists or not
08.        if valid_user
09.        #creates a session with username
10.            session[:user_id]=valid_user.user_name
11.        #redirects the user to our private page.
12.            redirect_to :action => 'private'
13.        else
14.            flash[:notice] = "Invalid User/Password"
15.            redirect_to :action=> 'login'
16.        end
17.end
```

and run it with a correct username and login, it tells me that

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in
>   UsersController#private
>
> Couldn't find User with ID=private

I want it to redirect to the private.html.erb page not search for it!

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you have a "private" method within your controller?

Comment: Which step are you at in the tutorial?  Step 7 adds a private method to the controller.

Comment: afaik the private method in the controller is just to ensure that only logged on users can access the private.html.erb page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `render :action => 'private'` instead of a redirect.